# 2 player game, dual 5 card draw match vs. coin flip

Tags: probability

$2$ people, (call them A and B), play a game where person A draws $5$ cards randomly (without replacement) from a well shuffled deck of $52$ playing cards and person B does the same but there are $2$ identical decks.  Each time A exactly matches (rank and suit) a card that B has, A gets one point.  B also flips a fair coin $5$ times per hand and get a point each time B gets heads.

So for example if A exactly matches $2$ of Bs card for a particular $5$ card hand A will receive $2$ points.  If B flips the coin $5$ times and gets $3$ heads then B will get $3$ points.  The score after $1$ round would then be B=$3$ and A=$2$.

One "twist" in this is A will get bonus points if A matches at least $3$ of Bs cards exactly.  $10$ points are awarded to A (instead of $3$) if $3$ cards exactly match, $4$ matches is $25$ points, and $50$ points if all $5$ cards match those of B.  So the possible points for each hand for A can be $0, 1, 2 ,10, 25$, or $50$.

So who has the mathematical advantage of having more points in the longrun?

$Update$:  I realize long after I submitted the question that I made a major error.  The points for A are supposed to all be multiplied by $5$ since A can only win once per game but B can win up to $5$ times per game.  So either do that or just count a B win as $0.2$ wins instead of $1$, thus the average expected # of wins for B will be $0.5$ per round.  Sorry about the mistake.

$Just for fun$:  If the points for B for a head are $0.2$ per head (maximum of $1$ point per game) and the points for A are $1$ point for $1$ matching number, $2$ points for $2$, $7$ points for $3$, $30$ points for $4$, and $635$ points for $5$, the probabilities are exactly equal at $0.5$ points per game (on average) for both A and B.  This might be a good problem for a probability class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just have to compare the expected values of both.

Let $B$ receive a set of $5$ cards. The probability that $A$ matches with $i$ of them is
 $5C_i\frac{47C_{5-i}}{52C_5}$

Taking some approximations..(since you wanted an estimate)

For $5$ card matching, it would be $50$ points $\times (\frac 1{50})^5$

For $1$ card matching, it would be $1$ point $\times (\frac 1{10})$

For $2$ card matching, it would be $2$ point $\times (\frac 1{50})$

For $3$ card matching, it would be $10$ point $\times (\frac 1{2500})$

For $4$ card matching, it would be $25$ point $\times (\frac 1{6250000})$

As you can clearly see, $1$ card matching has the highest expectation of all by a large margin. This is without including the probability of $0$ which is around $0.59$

However, for case $B$, He has most probability of $2.5$ heads which means $2.5$ points each game.

Hence, I would say, $B$ has an advantage

Comment: Why is the chance of a $5$ card match $\frac 1{50^5}?$  It should be $\frac 1{{52 \choose 5}}=\frac {5!47!}{52}$

Comment: @RossMillikan  I make an approximation .... for easier calculation and observation. I assume 52~51~50~49~49~47~50

Comment: I like that approximation using $50$ but I think you meant 52~51~50~49~48~47 and I think Ross is missing a ! (factorial) on the $52$ (denominator) in his comment.

Comment: @David You are right

Answer (score 3):

The "expected" winnings of $B$ per hand is 2.5 points per round.

The expected winnings of $A$ is:

$$\dfrac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{47}{4} + 2\binom{5}{2}\binom{47}{3} + 10\binom{5}{3}\binom{47}{2}+25\binom{5}{4}\binom{47}1 + 50\binom{5}{5}\binom{47}{0}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

I'm not inclined to do that calculation for you, but I suspect it is significantly less than $2.5$. That's because the odds of getting zero cards matching is $0.59$, and the odds of the "big" payoffs is very low.

Comment: I think you used $47$ 'cause They pick from the same deck. But, OP mentioned that there are two identical decks.

Comment: No, there are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{47}{4}$ ways to pick $5$ cards out of A's deck that match B's hand by exactly one card - you can pick one card from the five that $B$ chose and any four cards from the $47$ cards $B$ did not choose. @WinVineeth

Comment: Ya.. You are right. Thank you